# How to format a number to a string with a maximum total number of digits (irrespective of decimal separator)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simple way to format a number to a string with maximum total number of total digits (irrespective of whether digits are before or after the decimal separator)?

Nb. I do not want to fall-back to scientific notation (for large numbers, cut off all numbers right of the decimal separator, but exceed max number of digits). I think this makes strings more readable (e.g. in generated emails / reports).

E.g., for n_fixed_digits=6:

```
0.00123456789 -> "0.00123"
0.0000000123456789 -> "0.00000"
12345678.9 -> "12,345,679" (on overflow, all digits left of decimal point remain)
4.2 -> "4.2" (no trailing zero's)
```

The below works, but is cumbersome:

```
def str_fmt(num_in, n_fixed_digits=4):
    orig_decimals = len(str(num_in).split(".")[1]) if "." in str(num_in) else 0
    n_decimals = min(max(n_fixed_digits - len(str(num_in).split(".")[0]), 0), orig_decimals)
    return ("{:,." + str(n_decimals) + "f}").format(num_in)
```

Comment: Can you explain more why `12345678.9 -> "12345679"`?

Comment: `"4.2"` doesn't have 6 digits?

Comment: @CDJB -> I do want to fall back to scientific notation - i.e. only cut off digits after the decimal point

Comment: @wjandrea -> amended in the question. I don't want to 'pad' the string as that will make it less readable in my opinion